# Сравнение строк произвольного содержания и вывод процента схожести

Tags: c, строки, инспекция-кода

> Сравнение строк произвольного содержания и вывод процента схожести

Сравниваю каждое слово на наличие в строке, исходя из этого делаю вычисления и вывожу процент.

Без потоков задача решение выглядит примерно так:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int process(char *s, char *S2)
{ 
    char *instr;
    int col_in = 0; 
    instr = strstr(S2,s); //ищем слово в строке S2
    if(instr!=NULL)//если нашли
    {
     return strlen(s);//возвращаем количество символов в этом слове
    }
    else return col_in; //иначе возвращаем 0
}

void main(void)
{
char S1[20], S2[20];
    char sp[10]=" ";
    char *istr;
    int res = 0, col_words=0, tmp;
    double proc;  
    printf("Enter S1, S2\n");
    gets(S1);
    gets(S2);
    if(strlen(S1)<strlen(S2))
    {
    istr = strtok(S1,sp);//делим строку на слова
    while(istr != NULL)//пока есть слова
    {
       res += process(istr,S2);//возвращаем количество символов в слове, которое нашлось в строке S2
       printf("%d\n",res); 
       istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
       col_words++;//считаем количество слов, чтобы высчитать количество пробелов в строке S1
    } 
    proc = (res+col_words-1)*100/strlen(S2);
    }else{
    istr = strtok(S2,sp);
    while(istr != NULL)
    {
       res += process(istr,S1);
       printf("%d\n",res); 
       istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
       col_words++;
    } 
    proc = (res+col_words-1)*100/strlen(S1);
    }
    printf("%.1lf\n",proc);   
    return 0;

}
```

Как можно упростить и сократить код?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Весь код перелопачивать не буду, только основные моменты.

Для начала забудьте про `gets()`, она небезопасна. Даже так уже лучше:

```
fgets( string, sizeof(string), stdin );
```

А если речь про Linux, то есть [getline()](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getline.3.html).

(ещё непонятно зачем усложнять себе жизнь и на стадии написания/отладки основных алгоритмов заморачиваться вводом данных, когда можно строки прописать константами, а пользовательский ввод подключать уже когда всё будет готово)

Дальше, вот этот код:

```
istr = strtok(S1,sp);//делим строку на слова
while(istr != NULL)//пока есть слова
{
  res += process(istr,S2);
  printf("%d\n",res); 
  istr = strtok(NULL,sp);
  col_words++;
} 
proc = (res+col_words-1)*100/strlen(S2);
```

фактически повторяется два раза (см. [Don’t repeat yourself](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%E2%80%99t_repeat_yourself)). Его можно вынести в отдельную функцию и просто передавать ей разные аргументы в зависимости от условий (сравнения длин строк).

А вот функция `process()` вообще бесполезна, она легко заменяется на

```
res += strstr( s2, s1 ) ? strlen( s1 ) : 0;
```

или

```
if( strstr( s2, s1 ) ) res += strlen( s1 );
```